# WinForms: Trackbar button is blue in WIndows 10 only

Tags: windows, winforms, visual-studio-2010, trackbar

Hi I have an application that has a number of trackbars in it (an equalizer).  These trackbars are white in every OS except for Windows 10 where they are bright blue!.
So I created a simple WinForms app that had a form and a trackbar.
In Windows 7 it is white.  In Windows 10 it is blue!  Nothing I can do will fix this.
Any ideas?
I am using

```
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
```

But this does nothing at all if I remove it.
Thanks, Tom

Comment: Please post a comparison screenshot.

Comment: The thumb of the track bar is colored according to the visual style theme you have active on your machine.  Yes, the default theme in Win10 now makes it blue.  No doubt after an extensive usability study concluded that a gray thumb on a gray background was not ideal.  Hehe.  Use superuser.com to ask a question on how to change your theme settings.  Or do this the way most any programmer does it, if you don't like what pieces come in the Lego box then build your own.